# Proof that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}: (f(x))^n = f(nx)$ only has solutions of the form $f(x) = c^x$ for some constant $c$

Tags: recurrence-relations, functional-equations

I am looking for a proof (or a counterexample I suppose) that the recurrence equation (is that the right term here?) $(f(x))^n = f(nx)$ only has a solution of the form $ f(x)=c^x$ for some non-negative constant $c$. It is easy to verify that this is a correct solution but what's important to me is that no other solutions can exist. I would like to i) get verification that this is indeed true ii) see a proof of this, possibly some reference. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is this for EVERY value of $n$ or for ONE PARTICULAR value of $n$?  Are $n$ and $x$ integers, or real, or is $x$ real and $n$ an integer, or what?

Comment: What is the domain of $f$? What is the domain of $n$? I doubt that this is the case if you don't impose some conditions.

Comment: My bet is that you need continuity assumption to proove they are the only functions satisfying  this "equation". In this case it is true afaik.

Comment: @MichaelHardy $x \in \mathbb{R}$. The statement should say $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: (f(x))^n = f(nx)$, although I am also interested in knowing if it is true for $n \in \mathbb{R}$. $f$ is any well-defined function of a single variable.

Comment: Even if you have that equation for all integers $n$, these are not the only functions. Take any non-linear additive function $g$ i.e. solution to [Cauchy's functional equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_functional_equation) (Assuming axiom of choice, it is possible to construct pathological additive functions) and define $f(x)=e^{g(x)}$.

Comment: As far as i know this is how it goes : I will assume hat f is continuous and f(0)=1. First you apply your relation to x=1, which gives you $f(n)=f(1)^n$ for any integer ( i.e you have c=f(1) and you have showed the relation for $x\in N$. Applying the relation to $x=1/n$ gives you $f(1/n)=f(1)^{1/n}$. Combining this two gives you the validity on the relation $f(x)=c^x$ on rationnal and you finally need coninuity to establish it on all real.

Comment: On the other hand taking f(x) defined as follows gives you a counter example in the non continous case $f(x)=C_1 ^x$ on $\mathbb{Q}$ and $f(x)=C_2^x$ on $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$. Now since $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ are stable by multiplication with a rationnal number you have a counter example of course this is not a continuous function. It was only a sketch and i still wonder wether or not you have to impose $f(0)=1$ this is why I did not post it as an answer.